# ruby on rails display if page has been visited (pending, yes, no)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visited

I am using Rails 4 and PHPmyadmin

I designed a form that sends an email with two links, let's call them Link #1 and Link #2.

I need to know if the user that received the email has clicked on link #1 or link #2.

I already have the landing view #1 and view #2 with their corresponding id's, and can access both links.

The end result is that in my list table I need to display the status of every email sent with either:

- Pending (if user hasn't clicked on any link)
- Link #1 (if user clicked   on it)
- Link #2 (if user clicked on it)

I know that I need to associate the email id with the view id, but don't know how to do this.

Something like this:

```
EMAIL.......... LINK CLICKED
me@example.com  pending
john@example.com  Link 1
sonia@example.com  Link 2
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000925/tracking-impressions-visits-per-web-page) similar question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300259/rails-3-determine-if-a-user-has-viewed-data) other one,  however I don't know how to implement it in my app.

Comment: I don't know Ruby but check if there is a data structure like a HashMap<String, String> where you can store "john@example.com" -> "1". Then your html would have: name="emailsMap['john@example.com']"

Comment: Check this out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227571/how-to-iterate-over-a-hash-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks for that link, it helped me to understand the process a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each link relates to a method in the controller that renders the view.. in your case Link#1 and Link#2 will correspond to some specific action in some controller. You can place checks there against the user you have sent email.
Please tell if this helps

Comment: Allright, so I did what you said and that worked!  I created a controller and a method. Now I am able to save in the database the link id.  Now I need to know how to retrieve it, all I'm getting on a link.inspect is the <8883922xhh220>.  thanks a lot.

Comment: what are you storing and what do you want to retrieve?